# How to force google/youtube searches using the bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, linux-mint, bash-script

I'd like to know how to force the bash to do a Google or Youtube searches (in mozilla) of a given phrase. I'm also interested in a scripts that enters a Youtube video and recognizes if there is an advertisement in the beginning.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that information on how to bypass YouTube ads is off topic on SE. You can try these tips though: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/grabbing-your-music-youtube-do-it-your-way

Comment: This seems more like a perl/python et. al. kind of realm, since they are will have modules for youtube and google -- although I assume you could access the same HTTP API's in bash via `curl`.

Comment: Hi Tomer, welcome to Unix & Linux. As you may be aware from Math.SE, the Stack Exchange format works best when you ask a single question per post and that question can be authoritatively answered. You are asking two separate questions here. The latter (about ad-detecting scripts) might be off topic, but in either case, you are better off asking them as separate questions rather than in the same question; they are unrelated, and the likelihood of one person being able to answer both is much smaller than that of two persons each being able to answer one of the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you do not want to search for some special characters (like `&`), one of the most easy way to start a search is to put the following function

```
googleit() {
   xdg-open "http://google.com/search?q=$*"
}
```

into your `$HOME/.bashrc`.

After re-login or restarting the shell or sourcing this file, you can then simply type

```
$ googleit The phrase I want to search for
```

and your default browser should start with the corresponding search result.

Comment: +1 IDC that it isn't really what was asked for, that's a neato tip.

Comment: @krowe I understood Tomer's question that he asked how to do a search *in mozilla* from bash. I assume he means Mozilla's most well-known product Firefox. Therefore, my answer should be correct (at least as long as his default browser is Firefox).

Comment: I meant firefox... btw, my default is mozilla firefox.

Comment: IC, you're correct.